# Intuition for partial derivative with respect to both variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm going through MIT's Multivariable Calc course and we're on partial derivatives.  They give the following function:

$$f(x,y) = xy^2 + x^2y$$

and ask for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial y \partial x}$.

I understand how to find the partial derivatives, but I don't understand the intuition behind what the second one represents.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is "for a given y, how much does $f$ change relative to a small, positive increase in x".  Then for $\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial y \partial x}$, I have "for a given x, how much does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ change relative to a small, positive increase in y?"  But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ takes "a given y"... so how can we be allowed to fix y to get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, then move it again to get $\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial y \partial x}$?  So confused.

Comment: Those two variations are independent. You first fix $y$, but after you found $f_x(x,y)$ you don't need to keep $y$ fixed – you get a function of $x$ and $y$. And then you variate $y$ and fix $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of the derivatives as functions.

If you say that $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, then $g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is also a function of x and y.

This is just like 1-d functions.

$f'(x)$ is just as much a function of $x$ as $f(x)$

therefore, if $g(x,y)$ is differentiable then you can compute $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ no problem

Just think of it like, now that we got this $g(x,y)$, we just completely forget that we got it from $f(x,y)$. What's done is done. That derivative was computed and $g(x,y)$ is its own function